# CSS float: left not working here

Tags: css-float, css

Trying to get this image below:

[image: Text on right of image]

But here's what I have instead:

[image: Problem with float: left here]

I am using this code as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="floatright" style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="floatleft" style="width: 35%;">
        <img src="images/exhibitingopportunities.png" alt="Exhibiting Opportunities" style="border: none; width: auto; max-width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft sidespadding" style="width: 65%;">
        <h4>Exhibiting Opportunities</h4>
        <p class="desc">The Opportunity Finance Network Conference is a great place to connect with decision makers across the industry.  Reserve your booth space now&mdash;contact Katie Kirchner for more information.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="floatleft" style="width: 35%;">
        <img src="images/sponsorship_opportunities.png" alt="Sponsorship Opportunities" style="border: none; width: auto; max-width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="floatleft sidespadding" style="width: 65%;">
        <h4>Sponsorship Opportunities</h4>
        <p class="desc">Reserve your slot now to be a part of the CDFI industry's premier event!  The OFN Conference provides our partners with an unparalleled platform to connect with CDFIs, increase awareness of their organizations' work, and support and strengthen the practice of opportunity finance.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatleft
{
    float: left;
}

.floatright
{
    float: right;
}

.sidespadding
{
    padding-left: 1.2em;
    padding-right: 1.2em;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Can't get the text to float to the left of the actual image, like the image in the first pic.  OMG, what am I missing here?  Webpage here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/2013conf/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your padding, your % is greater than 100% with padding.
Or you can apply box-sizing http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

If you want space you can always add margin left or right but make sure your percentage calculates to 100% at the end

So

div 1 30% width with 5% margin right for example
div 2 65% width

So total = 100%

there are other ways to accomplish this but you get the idea now

Comment: Thank You, this helped tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

Padding adds to the total width, making it 65% + 2.4em
If backward compatibility with older versions of IE is not an issue you can use [CSS calc](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc)

Otherwise you have to wrap some div in order to create padding inside the element you want.